# How to query varchar and int

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this table

```
name   | prof      |grade
------------------------
yossi   math     100
tami    math     70
yossi   phisic   100
tami    phisic   100
oren    math     100
oren    phisic   80
dor     history  70
```

The query should return name of student which have grade 100 in math and phisic
The correct unswer is yossi
I used the following

```
SELECT name FROM [dbo].[Class_grade]
where prof in ('math', 'phisic') and grade = 100
```

but it returns more names why?
what is the right query?
Thanks

Comment: Answer to 'why?' is because your query searches for students that have a grade 100 in either 'math' or 'physics'

Answer (score 6):

```
select name
from Class_Grade
where grade = 100 and
      prof in ('math', 'phisic')
group by name
having count(distinct prof) = 2
```

Group by `name` and filter out the rows using `having`. Make sure you count the distinct occurrences of `prof`. In this case it is 2 because you have 2 values in your in clause.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier i misquoted the **`Question`**

You can use **[Group by caluse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)**

```
SELECT name FROM [Class_grade]
where prof in ('math', 'phisic') and grade = 100
group by (name)
having count(1)=2
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9308c/14)**

Comment: This returns even students who don't have `grade = 100` for both `math` and `phisic`

Comment: @DanielDinnyes I misquoted the Question

Answer (score 0):

group by and make suure you get two rows

```
SELECT name 
FROM Class_grade
WHERE prof in ('math', 'phisic') and grade = 100
GROUP BY name
HAVING count(*) = 2
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9308c/6

**EDIT**
you can grab distinct grades if the same student can have more than one 100% in a subject

```
SELECT name 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT name, prof, grade
  FROM Class_grade
  WHERE prof in ('math', 'phisic') and grade = 100
) class_grade
GROUP BY name
HAVING count(*) = 2
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79fd0/11

Comment: doesn't work if students can have multiple grades per subject: [example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79fd0/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT name FROM Class_grade
WHERE prof IN ('math', 'phisic') AND grade=100
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(name) > 1
```

Comment: doesn't work if students can have multiple grades per subject: [example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79fd0/3/0)

Answer (score 0):

The OP did not state a few details:

- What is the primary key on the table (i.e. can multiple lines exist for the same student for the same subject)
- What is the expected result when there are multiple students who match the criteria.

If we assume that one student can have multiple grades in the same subject, many of the other answers would be wrong with the `HAVING COUNT(*)` clauses. [Mikael Eriksson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17083049/244935) satisfies that assumption, and it is possibly more performant than my below solution (though functionally different a bit too):

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM [dbo].[Class_grade] cg1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Class_grade] cg2
  WHERE cg2.name = cg1.name
  AND cg2.prof = 'math'
  AND cg2.grade = 100)
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Class_grade] cg2
  WHERE cg2.name = cg1.name
  AND cg2.prof = 'phisic'
  AND cg2.grade = 100)
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Class_grade] cg2
  WHERE cg2.name = cg1.name
  AND cg2.prof in ('math','phisic')
  AND cg2.grade < 100)
```

The difference in the above code is that it will only select students who have only `grade = 100` for the `math` and `phisic` subjects, even if they could have more than one grade per subject. [See here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3c8a/2).

Answer (score 0):

```
            select Class_grade.name
            from Class_grade
            inner join Class_grade Class_grade2
            on Class_grade.Name = Class_grade2.name
            where Class_grade.Prof = 'math' and Class_grade.grade = 100
            and Class_grade2.prof = 'phisic' and Class_grade2.grade = 100
            group by Class_grade.Name
```

try not to use distinct, its a poor coding

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name  FROM [dbo].[Class_grade] where prof in ('math', 'phisic') and grade = 100
```

This would work as well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM [dbo].[Class_grade] where (prof = 'math' and grade = 100) OR (prof = 'phisics' and grade = 100)
```

Comment: this query return more than one name

Comment: Second one wouldn't work because prof can't be `math` and `phisic` at the same time

Comment: for my opinion the  "in ('math', 'phisic')" is not working as "and" operator that's why it return more than one answer